# is there alternative way to Read/Write History and Bookmarks of Chrome Browser in Android M

Tags: android

the latest M Developer Preview 2, there is no permission to Read/Write History and Bookmarks. my app was depends on this permission request.
is there any other alternative to read History and Bookmarks URL of Browser?

Comment: Did you find any work around? Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

From updated [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-bookmark-browser):
This release removes support for global bookmarks. The android.provider.Browser.getAllBookmarks() and android.provider.Browser.saveBookmark() methods are now removed. Likewise, the READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS and WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS permissions are removed. If your app targets Android 6.0 (API level 23) or higher, don't access bookmarks from the global provider or use the bookmark permissions. Instead, your app should store bookmarks data internally.

That's why there is no way how to access bookmarks since Android M.